# Chef isn't running my recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I've got a recipe which `chef` has run before, and I've now added some stuff to it and all I get is

```
$ sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb web.json
Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.2
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 0 resources
Chef Client finished, 0 resources updated
```

I've tried putting syntactically incorrect ruby in the recipe's `default.rb` in question, but it's just not breaking, nor nothing else is happening. What have I missed?

The solo.rb file is:

```
file_cache_path "/home/username/chef-solo"
cookbook_path "/home/username/chef-repo/cookbooks"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the `-j` option for the `web.json` file. The command should read:

```
$ sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j web.json
```